# Spark union large csv files and write to parquet file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a bunch of large csv files with the same schema. I wand to union these files and write the result to a parquet file, partitioned by column `file_name`.

Here's what I have done so far:

```py
children_files = hdfs.list("/landing/my_data/children_flow/")
df = spark.createDataFrame(
            spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(),
            dfSchema
)
df = df.withColumn("file_name", lit(None))
for one_file in children_files :
    df2 = spark.read.csv(os.path.join("/landing/my_data/children_flow/", one_file))
    df2 = df2.withColumn("file_name", lit(one_file.replace(".csv", "")))
    df = df.union(df2)
df.write.partitionBy("file_name").parquet("/staging/my_data/children_flow/")
```

The problem is that I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` errors.

I tried to do a

```
df.repartition(3000, "file_name").write.partitionBy("file_name").parquet("/staging/my_data/children_flow/")
```

but it's not working neither. Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are too many files in the HDFS location. Because of those many files and `union` being a *transformation* not an *action* Spark runs probably  OutOfMemory when trying to build the physical plan.

In any case, if you plan to read a lot of csv files with the same schema I would use Structured Streaming. To avoid writing manually the schema, you can infer it from an example file.

The code below shows the idea:

```py
# define input and output paths and checkpoint location
csvPath = "hdfs:///landing/my_data/children_flow/"
parquetPath = "hdfs:///staging/my_data/children_flow/"
checkpointLoc = "hdfs:///path/to/dir/"

# infer Schema from one example csv file
schemaDf = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", true).load(csvPath + "first.csv")
schema = schemaDf.schema

# create Stream by reading from csv and writing to parquet
df = spark.readStream \
  .format("csv") \
  .schema(schema) \
  .load(csvPath) \
  .withColumn("file_name", split(input_file_name(), "/")(4))

query = df.writeStream \
  .format("parquet") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .option("path", parquetPath) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLoc) \
  .partitionBy("file_name") \
  .start() \
  .awaitTermination()
```

If this runs again out of memory you may set the option "maxFilesPerTrigger" to a decent number. If it creates too many parquet files, you could in the end just read -> repartition -> write the parquet data once.

Comment: Hi @Arès, apologies for coming back this late. I was just about to test adding the required column "file_name" and I have updated my answer accordingly. Remember that `input_file_name()` will return the full path, that is why I am splitting it by "/" and then selecting the last item in the collection to get the file name.